# EWS open another mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

how can I open another mailbox via EWS? I have full access to the mailbox.

With the code I can open my personal mailbox.

```
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService 
$service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList 
        $mail, $password 
$service.URL = New-Object Uri("outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")        

# Set how many emails we want to read at a time  
$numOfEmailsToRead = 5  
  
# Index to keep track of where we are up to. Set to 0 initially.   
$index = 0  
# Do/while loop for paging through the folder   
do {   
    # Set what we want to retrieve from the folder. This will grab the first $pagesize emails  
    $view = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView($numOfEmailsToRead, $index)   
    # Retrieve the data from the folder   
    $findResults = $service.FindItems([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $view)   
    foreach ($item in $findResults.Items) {  
      # load the additional properties for the item  
      $item.Load($propertySet)  
  
      # Output the results  
      $msgProperty = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::MimeContent)  
      $email = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage]::Bind($service, $item.Id, $msgProperty)  
...
 } while ($findResults.MoreAvailable)
```

thank you for your support

Comment: Where does $service come from?

Comment: $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService  
 
$service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList 
   $mail, $password  $service.URL = New-Object Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")

Comment: Oh I guess my phone was scrolled down. Sorry! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Mailbox overload for the folderid object so change

```
 $findResults = $service.FindItems([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $view)
```

To something like

```
$MailboxName = "blah@blah.com"
$folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $MailboxName)
$findResults = $service.FindItems($folderid , $view)
```